# How can I abstract the following pattern? (using Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am learning Vue.js. I like that it is lightweight. I am creating a user interface where there are "Device" objects. Each Device has inputs and outputs that can be accessed by mDevice.inputs or mDevice.outputs. inputs and outputs are list of objects themselves with input/output name, id, and type.

The devices are displayed on screen as divs, and on the div, there is text "Inputs" and "Outputs". One can hover over these labels and mDevice.inputs and mDevice.outputs is displayed. Here is that part:

```
<div v-on:mouseover="device.showInputs = !device.showInputs">inputs</div>
                            <ul class="io-list" v-if="device.showInputs">
                                <li v-for="(e, idx) in device.inputs">
                                    {{e.id}} - {{ e.the_type }}
                                    <div 
                                        v-on:mouseover="e.showAvailableOutputs = !e.showAvailableOutputs"
                                        class="xpull-right" style="display:inline;font-size:1.5em;">»</div>
                                    <ul class="sub-io-list" v-if="e.showAvailableOutputs"
                                        v-on:mouseleave="e.showAvailableOutputs = !e.showAvailableOutputs">
                                        <li style="white-space:nowrap" v-for="io in setupOutputs">
                                            ({{io.device.model}}) - {{io.the_type}}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <div v-on:mouseover="device.showOutputs = !device.showOutputs">outputs</div>
                            <ul class="io-list" v-if="device.showOutputs">
                                <li v-for="(e, idx) in device.outputs">
                                    {{e.id}} - {{ e.the_type }}
                                    <div 
                                        v-on:mouseover="e.showAvailableInputs = !e.showAvailableInputs"
                                        class="xpull-right" style="display:inline;font-size:1.5em;">»</div>
                                    <ul class="sub-io-list" v-if="e.showAvailableInputs"
                                        v-on:mouseleave="e.showAvailableInputs = !e.showAvailableInputs">
                                        <li style="white-space:nowrap" v-for="io in setupInputs">
                                            ({{io.device.model}}) - {{io.the_type}}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

The lists are multi-level (2). There is repetition here that I want to abstract.

I tried this:

```
<template  v-for="x in ['inputs','outputs']">
                            <div v-on:mouseover="toggleShowIOs(device,x, false)">{{x}}</div>
                            <ul class="io-list" v-if="showIOs(device, x, false)">
                                <li v-for="(e, idx) in device[x]">
                                    {{e.id}} - {{ e.the_type }}
                                    <div 
                                        v-on:mouseover="toggleShowIOs(e,x, true)"
                                        class="xpull-right" style="display:inline;font-size:1.5em;">»</div>
                                    <ul class="sub-io-list" v-if="showIOs(e,x,true)"
                                        v-on:mouseleave="toggleShowIOs(e,x, true)">
                                        <li style="white-space:nowrap" v-for="io in setupOutputs">
                                            ({{io.device.model}}) - {{io.the_type}}
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            </template>
```

But it seems like x (weather it is 'inputs' or 'outputs') does not persist when passed to function toggleShowIOs. I am thinking because I did not declare it in data property of my vue instance.

What would be the simplest way to abstract this pattern of creating multilevel menu? Am I on the right track? I am thinking of creating a component.

Got another question, how bad is it to place functions in data or prop properties?

Edit:
Ok, I think I'm getting closer with this. This is what I have now:

```
Vue.component('hover-menu', {
    template: '#hover-menu-template',
    props: ['label','menuItems'],
    data : function() {
        return {
            show: false,
        }
    },
    methods: {
        flipAndEmit: function() {
            this.show = !this.show;
            this.$emit('flipAndEmit');
        }
    }
});
```

And the template:

```
<template id="hover-menu-template">
    <div v-on:mouseover="flipAndEmit" v-on:mouseleave="flipAndEmit">
        <div>{{ label }} » </div>
        <ul v-if="show" style="display:inline;background-color:#5BE;">
            <li is="hover-menu"
                v-for="(item, index) in menuItems"
                v-bind:label="item.id"
                v-bind:menu-items="menuItems"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>


<hover-menu label="Inputs" :menu-items="device.inputs"></hover-menu>
<hover-menu label="Outputs" :menu-items="device.outputs"></hover-menu>
```

The controls are still wonky, but I think this is the answer for now. Once it's all working I will post answer here. If any of you guys beat me to it, then better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I used the folder-tree example from the Vue.js documentation to guide me. Here are the templates and html:

```
<template id="menu-template">
  <div>
  <div>{{menu.name}}
    <span v-if="menu.options.length > 0" v-on:mouseenter="showOptions = !showOptions">&gt;&gt;</span>
    <span v-else v-on:click="selectOption">OK</span>
  </div>
  <menu-children :options="menu.options" v-if="showOptions" v-on:went-out="showOptions = !showOptions"></menu-children>
  </div>
</template>  
<template id="menu-options-template">
  <ul class="list" v-on:mouseleave="sendUp">
    <li v-for="choice in options">
      <amenu-parent v-if="choice.options" :menu="choice"></amenu-parent>
      <span v-else>{{ choice.name }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="r in root">
    <amenu-parent :menu="r"></amenu-parent>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the js:

```
Vue.component('amenu-parent', {
  template: "#menu-template",
  props: ['menu'],
  data: function() {
    return {
      showOptions: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    selectOption: function(v) {
      alert('clicked');
    }
  }
});
Vue.component('menu-children', {
  template: "#menu-options-template",
  props: ['options'],
  methods: {
    sendUp: function() {
      this.$emit("went-out");
    }

  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    root: [{
      name: 'a',
      options: [{
        name: '1',
        options: []
      }, {
        name: 'asdf',
        options: [{
          name: 'deep',
          options: []
        }]
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'number2',
      options: [{
        name: 'deep',
        options: []
      }]
    }]
  },
});
```

And some css:

```
body {
  font-size:1.8em;
}
.list > li {
  background-color:#EEE;
  width:300px;
}
```